# How to rename a document in MarkLogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have simple task to do but unable to find the exact solutions for this.I have saved a file as abc.xml in MarkLogic.How can i rename the file as some example.xml using XQuery?

Code which I tried:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
xdmp:document-rename ("/aaa.xml","/final.xml");
```

This is showing an error.

Comment: http://developer.marklogic.com/pipermail/general/2009-November/003999.html

Answer (score 5):

There is no way, that I know of, to change the document URI of an existing document.  The only way I can think of is to create a new document with the same content and the new URI, and delete the existing one, in the same transaction.

Where it gets tricky is to make sure to preserve the ownership, the permissions, all the properties, the property document, make sure that the old URI is not used anywhere to link to the existing document, etc.

But usually, the document URI is never really used.  You should first considering whether you really need to rename the document, and why.

(Note that saying "this is showing an error" is rarely useful on SO or on mailing lists, if you do not show what the error is.)

Comment: Thanks for including the part that the URI is not as important as the markup of the XML itself.  Is is good practice to get your information via searches, such as CTS:SEARCH, and not via URI, such as fn:doc("/thisfile.xml").

Answer (score 4):

Florent is correct, a true 'rename' is not possible, or perhaps not even meaningful.  ( analogy - rename a file from one disk to another )

"Move" however is meaningful (copy then delete in a transaction).
Defining "Move" is use case dependent - i.e. what metatdata also needs to 'move' ? permissions? collections ? document properties ? inherited permissions ?

xmlsh (http://www.xmlsh.org) implements a 'rename' (http://www.xmlsh.org/MarkLogicRename) command for the marklogic extension which is really a 'move', with the implemenation borrowed from postings on markmail (http://markmail.org/)

The implementation is the following XQuery - it doesnt do everything you might want and it might do more then you want.  YMMV

https://github.com/DALDEI/xmlsh/blob/master/extensions/marklogic/src/org/xmlsh/marklogic/resources/rename.xquery

( it was also written long ago - it is likely to benefit from improvement )

Comment: The GitHub link provided above is out of date because the `rename.xqy` file has changed directories. (Funny, considering the context.)

Here's a link to the version of the code at the time: https://github.com/xmlsh/xmlsh/blob/e887838adf1fe0682d757baf73ad5bdf1e295f0b/extensions/marklogic/src/org/xmlsh/marklogic/resources/rename.xquery

The current code (at the time of my writing) can be found here: https://github.com/xmlsh/xmlsh/blob/5952b84b0d9101530b8ad169c8c9abd2f3ebd198/extensions/marklogic/src/main/resources/org/xmlsh/marklogic/resources/rename.xquery

Answer (score 0):

I have working example this works for me.

`xquery version "1.0-ml";`

```
declare function local:document-rename(
$old-uri as xs:string, $new-uri as xs:string)
as empty-sequence()
{
    xdmp:document-delete($old-uri),
    let $permissions := xdmp:document-get-permissions($old-uri)
    let $collections := xdmp:document-get-collections($old-uri)
    return xdmp:document-insert(
      $new-uri, doc($old-uri),
      if ($permissions) then $permissions
      else xdmp:default-permissions(),
      if ($collections) then $collections
      else xdmp:default-collections(),
      xdmp:document-get-quality($old-uri)
     )
     ,
    let $prop-ns := namespace-uri(<prop:properties/>)
    let $properties :=
    xdmp:document-properties($old-uri)/node()
    [ namespace-uri(.) ne $prop-ns ]
    return xdmp:document-set-properties($new-uri, $properties)
};
```

(: function call :)
 local:document-rename ("/opt/backup/x.xml","y.xml");

Answer (score 0):

MarkLogic has a tutorial up addressing file renaming (moving):

https://developer.marklogic.com/recipe/move-a-document/

Importantly, it uses the function xdmp:lock-for-update() to prevent modifications to the source file while it is being copied to the target location.

Also, if you are doing a batch renaming you'll want to make sure that each file URI you rename corresponds to a document in the database or you'll get runtime errors.